# Ruby - Issues iterating through multiple strings and populating arrays

Tags: ruby

I have a `response` variable that has the following strings in it:

`response` variable (this output I pulled from a telnet session, which I'm not showing below in the code for the sake of simplifying):

```
mydummyhost# show ip bgp 43.245.43.105
BGP routing table entry for 43.245.43.0/24
Paths: (2 available, best #1, table Default-IP-Routing-Table)
  Not advertised to any peer
  38561 2914 55432, (aggregated by 55532 202.68.67.134)
    202.158.215.44 from 201.158.202.44 (202.158.215.62)
      Community: 7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001
      Last update: Tue Sep 22 12:25:17 2020

  38561 2914 55433, (aggregated by 55433 202.68.67.135)
    202.158.215.52 from 202.158.215.52 (202.158.215.62)
      Community: 7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001
      Last update: Mon Sep 21 06:44:58 2020
```

I have a piece of code that I'm using to try to iterate through the string lines above and basically get the following result :

Required result:

```
43.245.43.105 is domestic peering (On-Net) originated by AS 55432 via path 38561 2914 55432
43.245.43.105 is domestic peering (On-Net) originated by AS 55433 via path 38561 2914 55433
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/telnet'

ipaddress = "43.245.43.105"
cat = []
response = ""
origin = []
paths = []
net = []
community = []

onoffnet= {
  ond:"domestic (On-Net)",
  oni:"international research (On-Net)",
  opd:"domestic peering (On-Net)",
  ofd:"domestic transit (Off-Net)",
  opi:"international peering (Off-Net)",
  ofi:"international transit (Off-Net)"
}

response.each_line do |line|

  if line  =~ /BGP routing table entry for (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*)/
    net[i] = $1
  elsif line =~ /Community: (.*)$/
    community[i] =  $1
  elsif line  =~ /^\s+([0-9\ ]+),.*/
    paths, aggregatedBy = line.split(", ")
    paths[i] = paths.strip
    origin[i] == aggregatedBy.split(" ")[2]
  elsif line =~ /Last update:/
    i += 1
  end
end

  if i == 0
    print "ERROR, no data found for the IP."
  else
    i = 0
    net.each do | ip |
      if community[i] =~ /7575\:1000/
        cat[i] = onoffnet.fetch(:ond)
      elsif community[i] =~ /7575\:1001/
        cat[i] = onoffnet.fetch(:oni)
      elsif community[i] =~ /7575\:1002/
        if community[i] =~ /7575\:6001/
          cat[i] = onoffnet.fetch(:opd)
        else
          cat[i] = onoffnet.fetch(:opi)
        end
      elsif community[i] =~ /7575\:1003/
        if community[i] =~ /7575\:6001/
          cat[i] = onoffnet.fetch(:ofd)
        else
          cat[i] = onoffnet.fetch(:ofi)
        end
      end
      i += 1
   
      if origin[i].to_s.length > 0 && paths[i].to_s.length > 0
        puts "#{ipaddress} is cat[i] network ip[i] originated by AS #{origin} via path #{paths} ."
      else
        puts #{ipaddress} + "is" +  cat[i] + "network" + ip[i] + "\n"
        puts "Test"
      end
  end
end
```

When I ran this, only "Test" is shown as output :

```
[root@mydummyhost]# ./telnet.rb

Test
```

Basically I'm trying to use `line =~ /Last update:/` to determine that I have another separate paths and origin to display by incrementing `i`, if that makes sense.

So I know it had hit the `if` condition, however I'm not sure why its not showing the first print line `puts #{ipaddress} + "is" +  cat[i] + "network" + ip[i] + "\n"` , this appears to be empty.

### EDIT:

After changing `puts #{ipaddress} + "is" +  cat[i] + "network" + ip[i] + "\n"` to `puts "#{ipaddress} is #{cat[i]} network #{ip[i]}\n"` (as suggested by @trueunlessfalse thanks!), I can now see an output :

```
[root@dummyhost]# ./telnet.rb
43.245.43.105 is  network 3
```

Unfortunately this isnt even close to the required result I'm looking for.

I know somehow the problem is with the way I was iterating that `response` var and populating the arrays - I have a perl code that works and am trying to convert that to ruby - , I'm just not sure how to fix this or what is a better way of going through that output.

Any suggestions how I should iterate `response` so the arrays can be populated based on the `i` value that gets incremented when it comes to the end of the "block" marked by `Last update:`?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected result appears to depend on the following types of values contained in the given string:

- BGP ip (e.g., `"43.245.43.105"`)
- path values (e.g., `"38561 2914 55432"`)
- originated values (e.g., `"38561"`)
- community values (e.g., `"7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001"`)

I suggest you first concentrate on extracting these values, after which it is fairly straightforward to construct the desired strings. My answer is limited to this initial task.

To produce some numbers I will first construct your string `response`.

```
response =<<~BITTER_END
mydummyhost# show ip bgp 43.245.43.105
BGP routing table entry for 43.245.43.0/24
Paths: (2 available, best #1, table Default-IP-Routing-Table)
  Not advertised to any peer
  38561 2914 55432, (aggregated by 55532 202.68.67.134)
    202.158.215.44 from 201.158.202.44 (202.158.215.62)
      Community: 7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001
      Last update: Tue Sep 22 12:25:17 2020

  38561 2914 55433, (aggregated by 55433 202.68.67.135)
    202.158.215.52 from 202.158.215.52 (202.158.215.62)
      Community: 7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001
      Last update: Mon Sep 21 06:44:58 2020
BITTER_END
```

I don't know much about Telnet, but it appears `response` contains a block of data that begins with a line that starts with 'mydummyhost'. I have written this to permit multiple such blocks (each beginning with a line that begins, 'mydummyhost'), so as a first step I will apply [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regular expression as follows.

```
arr = response.scan(/^mydummyhost\D+.+?(?=\z|^mydummyhost)/m)
  #=> ["mydummyhost# show ip bgp 43.245.43.105\nBGP routing table entry for 43.245.43.0/24\nPaths: (2 available, best #1, table Default-IP-Routing-Table)\n  Not advertised to any peer\n  38561 2914 55432, (aggregated by 55532 202.68.67.134)\n    202.158.215.44 from 201.158.202.44 (202.158.215.62)\n      Community: 7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001\n      Last update: Tue Sep 22 12:25:17 2020\n\n  38561 2914 55433, (aggregated by 55433 202.68.67.135)\n    202.158.215.52 from 202.158.215.52 (202.158.215.62)\n      Community: 7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001\n      Last update: Mon Sep 21 06:44:58 2020\n"]
```

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
/
^mydummyhost\D+   # match 'mydummyhost' at the beginning of a line followed
                  # by 1+ characters other than digits (\D)
.+                # match 1+ characters, including line terminators
?                 # make previous match lazy (aka non-greedy)
(?=               # begin a positive lookahead
  \z              # match end of string
  |               # or
  ^mydummyhost    # match '^mydummyhost' at the beginning of a line
)                 # end positive lookahead
/mx               # specify multiline (\m) and free-spacing regex definition modes
```

Multiline mode (named differently by other languages) causes the dot to match line terminators (\n and \r\n) as well as other characters.

You will see here that `arr` contains a single element. The next step is to map `arr` to values for each block. To simplify the presentation I will assume the string contains one block, namely, `response`, but it should be evident how it could be generalized.

*Extract the BGP ip*

```
bgp_rgx = /^mydummyhost\D+\K\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}$/
bgp_ip = response[bgp_rgx]
  #=> "43.245.43.105"
```

See [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). The regex in free-spacing mode:

```
bgp_rgx =
  /
  ^mydummyhost\D+ # match 'mydummyhost' at the begining of a line (^),
                  # followed by 1+ characters other than digits (\D)
  \K              # reset the beginning of the match to the current location
                  # and discard any previously-matched characters from the
                  # match that is returned
  \d{1,3}         # match 1-3 digits
  (?:\.\d{1,3})   # match '.' followed by 1-3 characters, save to a
                  # non-capture group 
  {3}             # execute the foregoing non-capture group 3 times
  $               # match end of line
  /x              # specify free-spacing regex definition mode
```

*Extract the path values*

```
path_rgx = /(?<=^ {2})\d+(?: +\d+){2}(?=,)/
paths = response.scan(path_rgx)
  #=> ["38561 2914 55432", "38561 2914 55433"]
```

In free-spacing mode:

```
path_rgx =
  /
  (?<=^[ ]{2})     # use a positive lookbehind (?<=...) to assert that the
                   # match that follows is preceded by two spaces at the
                   # beginning of a line
  \d+              # match 1+ digits
  (?:[ ]+\d+)      # match 1+ spaces followed by 1+ digits, save to non-capture group 
  {2}              # execute the foregoing non-capture group 2 times
  (?=,)            # use a positive lookahead (?=...) to assert that the
                   # preceding match is followed by ','
  /x               # specify free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Note that when writing regular expressions in free-spacing mode all spaces are removed before the expression is parsed. It is necessary, therefore, to protect all spaces that should not be stripped out. I've done that by putting a space character in a capture group (`[ ]`). There are other ways to protect spaces, but that's not important.

*Extract the originated values from the path values*

```
originated = paths.map { |s| s[/\d+/] }
  #=> ["38561", "38561"]
```

The regex reads, "match one or more digits".

*Extract the community values*

```
community_rgx = /^ {6}Community: +\K\d+:\d+(?: +\d+:\d+)+/
community = response.scan(community_rgx)
  #=> ["7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001",
  #    "7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001"]
```

In free-spacing mode:

```
community_rgx =
  /
  ^[ ]{6}          # match 6 spaces at beginning of a line
  Community:[ ]+   # match 'Community:' followed by 1+ spaces
  \K               # reset the beginning of the match to the current location
                   # and discard any previously-matched characters from the
  \d+:\d+          # match 1+ digits, ':', 1+ digits
  (?:[ ]+\d+:\d+)  # match 1+ spaces, 1+ digits, ':', 1+ digits, save 
                   # to a non-capture group
  +                # execute the foregoing non-capture group 1+ times
  /x               # specify free-spacing regex definition mode
```

*Combine values into a hash (optional)*

```
params = {
  bgp_ip: bgp_ip,
  values: originated.zip(paths, community).map do |o,p,c|
             { originated: o, path: p, community: c }
          end
}
  #=> {:bgp_ip=>"43.245.43.105",
  #    :values=>[
  #      {:originated=>"38561", :path=>"38561 2914 55432",
  #         :community=>"7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001"},
  #      {:originated=>"38561", :path=>"38561 2914 55433",
  #       :community=>"7575:1002 7575:2462 7575:3002 7575:6001 7575:8001"}
  #    ]
  #   }
```

See [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip).

Again, if the string contains multiple blocks an array of hashes such as `params` would be returned.

Comment: Hurray! Cary, because of your excellent detailed explaination, I managed to correct my piece of code so it can now output the results I'm looking for.  I am very very grateful thank you. There was just one thing I observed regarding ensuring a single element / string returned gets  enforced as an array, but thats a separate question. And I managed to fix that with `Array(bgp_ip).each do`. Learnt a lot today!

Answer (score 2):

Update: This answer is not adressing all issues with the authors code, but only the question why one of the `puts` is not giving any output.

I would have expected this line:

```
puts #{ipaddress} + "is" +  cat[i] + "network" + ip[i] + "\n"
```

to throw an error, because I never before tried to interpolate a string without first opening a string.

I tried this in the console, and indeed it just prints an empty line:

```
irb(main):002:0> a = "foo"
=> "foo"
irb(main):003:0> puts #{a}

=> nil
```

However this works as expected:

```
irb(main):004:0> puts "#{a}"
foo
=> nil
```

Try rewriting this line as:

```
puts "#{ipaddress} is #{cat[i]} network #{ip[i]}\n"
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Indeed I tested the proposed change

Comment: thanks @trueunlessfalse with your change it does output `43.245.43.105 is  network 3` now. Unfortunately its not the output its looking for, although I'm happy now its saying something! Based on that `response` output it should really hit the `if origin[i].to_s.length > 0 && paths[i].to_s.length > 0`  but I dont think I'm doing the array iterations and calling properly. Looking for the right way to approach it. Appreciate the effort though. @CarySwoveland thank you I'm very curious. Will do a bit more reading this morning too.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I identified the problem blocking the author from proceeding with debugging their code. If afterwards the next question becomes obvious the author can ask again. It is nice of you to debug and fix someones entire code, but I don't think that this is what you can expect when asking a very broad question on SO.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Fair enough, I updated my answer, and upvote yours.

Comment: You may want to remove your comments. I'll delete this one as well.